# I have one of my app listed on Playstore, i am trying to test updated app on my mobile without uninstalling old. But it's showing app not installed

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, google-play, google-play-console

I am using signed release apk with same signing key as that of PlayStore One. I am using version 12.8 in new while the app on playstore has version 12.7. What could be the possible reasons for this. Please help.

I tried everything possible but i am unable to install the new update without uninstalling the old one.

Comment: If you can not update it then the signing keys don't match. You should extract the APK(s) you have installed from PlayStore and check their signature using `apksigner` tool. Then you will see which signing cert(s) were used.